# C++ Error with operator= of unique_ptr using std::move(nullptr)

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have seen [this](http://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/polymorphism-explained-part-2/) and I have corrected my code:

```
int solutionChooser = m_configFile.getChosenSolution();
ISolution* currentSolution;
switch (solutionChooser)
{
  case 1:
  {
    currentSolution = new Solution1());
    break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
    currentSolution = new Solution2());
    break;
  }
  case 3:
  {
    currentSolution = new Solution3());
    break;
  }
  case 4:
  {
    currentSolution = new Solution4());
    break;
  }
  default:
  {
    std::cout << "The specified solution does not exists\n";
    return;
  }
}
```

using `unique_ptr` as:

```
int solutionChooser = m_configFile.getChosenSolution();
std::unique_ptr<ISolution> currentSolution;
switch (solutionChooser)
{
  case 1:
  {
    currentSolution.reset(new Solution1());
    break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
    currentSolution.reset(new Solution2());
    break;
  }
  case 3:
  {
    currentSolution.reset(new Solution3());
    break;
  }
  case 4:
  {
    currentSolution.reset(new Solution4());
    break;
  }
  default:
  {
    currentSolution = std::move(nullptr); // here is the error
    std::cout << "The specified solution does not exists\n";
    return;
  }
}
```

and now I am getting the error below:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<ISolution>’ and ‘std::remove_reference<long int>::type {aka long int}’)
```

I have `ISolution` as interface and the `SolutionX` are classes derived from `ISolution`

How to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove that line from the default case. You don't seem to need it.

Comment: Try using `currentSolution.reset(nullptr)`; the error is because nullptr is(at least on visual studio) implicitly convertable to int, and int is not pointer of any type. alternatevly try doing `std::move<ISolution*>(nullptr)

Comment: `move(nullptr)`? Hey, I was still going to use that `nullptr`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` has deleted `operator=`, that is why you can not use it.

To reset the `std::unique_ptr`, use `reset()` method :

```
currentSolution.reset(nullptr);
```

but you do not have to do it, since the initial value is `nullptr` anyway.

Comment: Seems to work like you say. Not working: `move<ISolution>(nullptr)`, `move<ISolution*>(nullptr)`

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is wrong, by n3376 `std::unique_ptr` should have following overloading

```
unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept;
```

so, your code should work fine.

Comment: I am using g++9 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments so I'll just post my idea about the answer..
I believe your problem is the copy constructor. The operator = is not defined with unique_ptr so instead you'll have to use a move constructor. I don't remember the correct syntax but it should be something similar to:

```
/* Header file */
std::unique_ptr<ISolution> currentSolution;

/* CPP file */
std::unique_ptr<ISolution> currentSolution2(new ISolution);
currentSolution = std::move(currentSolution2);
```

There's probably some mistakes here but hopefully it can get you to the right track. If you want a working example, I got one on floobits, user Simple2012.
Link here: https://floobits.com/Simple2012/Laboration_SearchMethods
Check arr.h and arr.cpp for a concrete example, however I'm using an array there instead of a class, not much difference though.